# how deploy rails-project via rvm and apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rvm, passenger

please help solve the problem.

on ubuntu14 i install apache2(with passenger module), rvm and several versions rails. i try start these rails-projects on localhost or on web.

i create two gemset:

```
md1@md1 /var/log/apache2 $ rvm gemset list_all

gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p643 (found in /home/md1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643)
   (default)
   global
   proj_r4_0

gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /home/md1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
   (default)
   global
=> proj_r4
```

after i create on  /home/md1/rails/proj_r4 project on rails 4.2.4 
and i create on  /home/md1/rails/proj_r4_0 project on rails 4.0.0

for every project i create file .rvmrc which contails:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@proj_r4
```

and

```
rvm use 2.2.1@proj_r4_0
```

my settings for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin prozaik81-2@yandex.ru
        DocumentRoot /home/md1/rails/proj_r4/public
        ServerName proj_r4.ru

        RailsEnv production
        <Directory /home/md1/rails/proj_r4/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin prozaik81-2@yandex.ru
        DocumentRoot /home/md1/rails/proj_r4_0/public
        ServerName proj_r4_0.ru

        RailsEnv production
        <Directory /home/md1/rails/proj_r4_0/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


127.0.0.1       localhost proj_r4.ru proj_r4_0.ru
```

but at addresses /home/md1/rails/proj_r4 and /home/md1/rails/proj_r4_0 i see follow error message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it
>   shortly. Information for the administrator of this website
>
> The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while
>   starting your web application. Because you are running this web
>   application in staging or production mode, the details of the error
>   have been omitted from this web page for security reasons.
>
> Please read the Passenger log file to find the details of the error.
>
> Alternatively, you can turn on the "friendly error pages" feature (see
>   below), which will make Phusion Passenger show many details about the
>   error right in the browser.
>
> To turn on friendly error pages:
>
> ```
> Nginx integration mode
> Apache integration mode
> Standalone mode
> ```

i try run in console:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and set to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

but it not solved problem

also apache log:

```
[ 2015-11-08 23:04:18.3074 7652/7f46ff38d700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 747dc5c0. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 7895 stdout: 
App 7895 stdout: 
[ 2015-11-08 23:06:49.4866 7652/7f47059f8700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/md1/rails/proj_r4: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: eceeb28e
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-0tPkpl.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /home/md1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /home/md1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


[ 2015-11-08 23:06:49.5176 7652/7f46ff38d700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is eceeb28e. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`
Looking at this i would guess you somehow miss bundler gem on target host.
Try to install

`gem install bundler`

manually for your rvm environment.